# Filling a JavaFX TableView with DataFX

Tags: csv, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to fill a TableView with the data from a csv-file with the datafx extension.

Unfortunately the tableview is empty and I'm not able to find any example anywhere which indicates my mistake.

```
    DataSourceReader dsr1 = new FileSource("Example3.csv");

    CSVDataSource ds1 = new CSVDataSource(dsr1);
    TableView table1 = new TableView();
    table1.setItems(ds1.getData());
    table1.getColumns().addAll(ds1.getColumns());

    System.out.println("#ds1 " + ds1.getData().size());  //returns zero
```

The code does not throw an exception, which makes it even more mysterious.

Comment: What version of DataFX are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even though the question is to fill the TableView with the DataFX extension here is a solution without DataFX:

1. Create a class that represents a list item of your tableView e.g.:

   ```
   public class YourItem { 
    private String itemID;
    private String itemTitle;

    public String getItemID() {
         return itemID;
    }

    public void setitemID(String itemID) {
         this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    //getter and setter for the other vars, I am lazy. }
   ```
2. Parse your csv file and return a `List<YourItem>`

   there are several tutorials and examples for that, you can find one here:
   http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/ Important is that you create a `List` of `YourItem` objects where each row is a `YourItem` object
3. Convert your `List<YourItem>` into an `ObservableList<YourItem>`

`ObservableList<YourItem> obsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(yourList);`

4. finally set the items to your TableView:
   *I won't mention that you need to create Columns for your TableView*

   `TableView<YourItem> test = new TableView<YourItem>();
   test.setItems(obsList);`